# How to write mathematical definitions correctly

Tags: math-mode

So I have troubles running my file at the moment. That's why I wanna be sure about the subsequent expression:

```
\begin{equation} \label{IM}

\left(\text{IM}\right)_\text{frequency} = mf_1 + nf_2 \text{ with } m,n \in \mathbb{Z^2}, 
\end{equation}
```

So I want the Z to have an exponent 2. Is this achieved by this code line?

Comment: you do not need (and shouldn't use) `\left` and `\right` here, also  use `\mathrm` for IM and frequency, not `\text`

Comment: And don't have blank lines in equation environments.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that you are having troubles with that code `;-)`

If you try to compile it, the first error will be

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
```

The empty line is interpreted as a new paragraph, which is allowed only in text mode. However, after `\begin{equation}` TeX is in (display) math mode, so it thinks you forgot a `$`, and put it in. Pressing enter raises now

```
! Display math should end with $$
```

i.e. which is a follow-up error of the `$` TeX inserted before. Note that only the first error message is meaningful: everything coming after that isn't usually helpful. But let us forget that and keep pressing `<enter>`: this time you'll run into

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

again. Why? Because TeX now has switched into text mode but has encountered `\left`, which is a math-mode macro, so again it inserts a `$`. And then the next problem: Opening math with `$` (inline math) and closing with `\end{equation}` (display math) tries to make an equation number, which isn't possible in inline math, and you get the error

```
! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode
```

I could go on, but let's stop here: to make the long story short, the code should be

```
\begin{equation} \label{IM}
(\mathrm{IM})_\mathrm{frequency} = m f_1 + n f_2 \text{ with } (m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2, 
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation} \label{IM}
(\mathrm{IM})_\mathrm{frequency} = m f_1 + n f_2 \text{ with $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$,}
\end{equation}
```

You almost never need `\left` and `\right`, and you can surely omit them here. As David pointed out in his comment, `\mathrm` is the better choice than `\text` for 'IM' and 'frequency'. The exponent to `\mathbb{Z}` must be given outside of `\mathbb`, otherwise you'll get no error but a nasty surprise:

[image]